# ungroup a column in postgres

Tags: postgresql, loops, group-by

I have a table, built from a cron. 
Lets say it has two columns, Hours and Jobname. eg: Job 1 runs for hours {1,2,3,4} and job 2 runs for hours {3,4,5,6}.

I need to have a query, which ungroups the column hours and list the jobs for each hour.

Expected Output:

```
Hours      Job Name
1          Job 1
2          Job 1
3          Job 1, Job2
4          Job 1, Job2
5          Job 2
6          Job 2
```

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` for that table.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your jobs column is a *comma separated list of data type `text` (or similar)* - separated by `', '` - I convert it to an array with [`string_to_array()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and then [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) it to separate rows:

```
SELECT hour, unnest(string_to_array(jobs, ', ')) AS job
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY 1;
```

You could also use [`regexp_split_to_table(jobs, ', ')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), which is simpler but does not scale as well with longer strings.

Related questions:

- [Create table from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755075/create-table-from-string)
- [Count the number of rows that contain a letter/number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538051/count-the-number-of-rows-that-contain-a-letter-number)

In Postgres **9.3** or later, use a `LATERAL` join instead. Assuming the query is *simple* and jobs is defined `NOT NULL`, this works and typically return jobs according to the original order of elements:

```
SELECT hour, job
FROM   tbl, unnest(string_to_array(jobs, ', ')) job  -- implicitly LATERAL
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7ca8b/1)

For more complex queries or if `jobs` can be `NULL`:

```
SELECT hour, job
FROM   tbl
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(string_to_array(jobs, ', '))
       WITH ORDINALITY AS j(job, ord) ON TRUE
ORDER  BY hour, ord;
```

`WITH ORDINALITY` requires Postgres **9.4** is only needed to *guarantee* original order of array elements. Details:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table of jobs, you can approach this as a join:

```
select cront.hour, j.name
from cront join
     jobs j
     on ', '||jobs||', ' like '%, '||j.name||', '
```